# calling function from prototype function

Tags: javascript

I have a prototype function in javascript...  I'd like to be able to call another function from that prototyped function.

```
var objMap = new Map(500,500);
var myCities = objMap.genValues(5);

function Map(sizeX, sizeY) {
    this.sizeX = sizeX;
    this.sizeY = sizeY;
}
Map.prototype = {
    genValues: function (number) {
        validateValues(number);
    }
}

function validateValues(num){
    alert(num);
}
```

in my console I get the following error:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'genValues'

When I don't add the function call to validateValues I don't get the error.
Is there a way to do this?  I'd like to be able to call functions in a recursive manner as well.

**UPDATE!**

I fixed my code in the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wNLYT/):  I still get the same error.
It sounds like I'm using the prototype functionality/methodology incorrectly as I can't call functions from within that?  Is that right?

Comment: You are missing a closing `}` to end `genValues`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are constructing the `Map` instance before you are assigning the prototype; and you're calling the method before you create it. Objects that are instantiated after that assignment would have a `genValues` method. Two fixes:

```
function validateValues(num){
    alert(num);
}

function Map(sizeX, sizeY) {
    this.sizeX = sizeX;
    this.sizeY = sizeY;
}
// alter the existing prototype object instead of overwriting it
Map.prototype.genValues = function (number) {
    validateValues(number);
}

// create instances only after the "class" declaration is done!
var objMap = new Map(500,500);
var myCities = objMap.genValues(5);
```

Comment: As an addendum for the OP's benefit: the reason `new Map()`  works before the declaration `function Map() { ... }` is because function declarations are [hoisted to the top of their containing function](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html). However, while the `Map` constructor is hoisted (and thus `Map` can be used freely anywhere in the same function as the declaration, before or after), the assignment of `Map.prototype` is *not* hoisted, so `Map.prototype.genValues` is available only *after* its assignment.

Comment: @apsillers: Thanks for the link, I had no time to search for a good one.

Comment: @apsillers Why isn't `Map.prototype` hoisted?  Would this be hoisted `Map.prototype.genValues = function() {}`?

Comment: @neurosnap: Assignments or literals are never hoisted. Only declarations are.