# Trigger one prototype function from another (including itself)

Tags: javascript, prototype

### The Problem

I have created a constructor called `Game`. Then, I tried to expand it's functionality by adding two new functions (`update` and `render`) using prototype.

However, I'd like my `update` function to be able to call both **itself** and then call `render`.

### My Code

```
var Game = function(){

};

Game.prototype.update = function(){
    requestAnimationFrame(this.render);
    requestAnimationFrame(this.update);
};
Game.prototype.render = function(){
  console.log('Rendering');
};

var game = new Game();
game.update();
```

### What I have also Tried

```
requestAnimationFrame(render);
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

And..

```
requestAnimationFrame(Game.render);
requestAnimationFrame(Game.update);
```

And...

```
requestAnimationFrame(Parent.render);
requestAnimationFrame(Parent.update);
```

But due to some (**glaringly obvious**) gaps in my javascript knowledge, I can't make this work. It appears as if `this` and `parent` are both referring to `window` - I'm guessing that's because of how the functions were created.

This is the error I receive;

> Game.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute
>   'requestAnimationFrame' on 'Window': The callback provided as
>   parameter 1 is not a function.

### Questions I've already found

I've already found the following questions on SO, but they don't appear to be all that helpful to this particular problem.

[Javascript multiple prototype functions - how to call one from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143926/javascript-multiple-prototype-functions-how-to-call-one-from-another)

[calling function from prototype function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938323/calling-function-from-prototype-function)

Comment: I thought about trying that, but I couldn't work out where to place it. Would the definition of self be in the constructor, and the call in the prototype?

Comment: @Rajesh I still wondering why you use a variable for storing `this` reference. That is completely unnecessary. https://jsfiddle.net/pberkxt9/

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy check the [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pberkxt9/1/). I tried my assumption, but even that is not working.

Comment: @downvoters - Comments welcome.

Comment: @Rajesh Oh.. for a recursive call it is required.

Comment: Yes. But question is, if I'm storing reference in `self`, why is `self` pointing to window? I mean, if I'm calling `self.update`, this should point to `self`, or we are just passing function and since it is invoked later, this will point to window.

Comment: @Rajesh It looks like it's the same problem as my original post - as `self` is defined in the prototype function, `self` is redefined to `this` on the second recursion (and on the second recursion, `this` is pointing to window)

Comment: @Lewis so I guess, link previously shared explains issue correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those lines

```
requestAnimationFrame(this.render);
requestAnimationFrame(this.update);
```

should be

```
requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));
requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this));
```

Otherwise, in the second execution of your recursion, keyword `this` will refer to `window` object instead of `Game`. And `window.update` is obviously not a function, as the error specified.

Comment: Interesting, thank you - I wonder why the reference to this is destroyed after the `first run` - it seems counter-intuitive. What would I look up for more information about this?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback

Answer (score 1):

You have lost the reference to the Game object, try binding 'this' like so:

```
var Game = function(){

};

Game.prototype.update = function(){
    requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));
    requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this));
};
Game.prototype.render = function(){
  console.log('Rendering');
};

var game = new Game();
game.update();
```